# Adding padding to a tkinter widget only on one side

Tags: python, tkinter, padding

How can I add padding to a tkinter window, without tkinter centering the widget?
I tried:

```
 self.canvas_l = Label(self.master, text="choose a color:", font="helvetica 12")
 self.canvas_l.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=S, ipady=30)
```

and

```
 self.canvas_l = Label(self.master, text="choose a color:", font="helvetica 12")
 self.canvas_l.grid(row=9, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky=S, pady=30)
```

I want 30px padding only on the top of the label.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The padding options `padx` and `pady` of the `grid` and `pack` methods can take a **2-tuple** that represent the left/right and top/bottom padding.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        l1 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Hello")
        l2 = tk.Label(self.root, text="World")
        l1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(100, 10))
        l2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10, 100)) 

app = MyApp()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this behavior described anywhere semi-official? My two favorite tk resources, [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) and [New Mexico Tech](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html), don't give any hint that padding can be uneven in this way. Secret undocumented behavior?

Comment: @Kevin: tkinter is just a pythonic wrapper around an embedded tcl interpreter which includes the tk library. The canonical docs for tk mention this feature. Here's the reference: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm#M16

Comment: Works on Grid padx/pady, but not on Frame. Probably many more exceptions exists

Comment: @DanielBraun: it will work for frames, too. Tkinter doesn't care what type of widget it is.

Comment: @BryanOakley actually `padx` and `pady` are standard tk widget options so we can use them in the dunder `init` method also. Using the 2 integer tuple form there will raise an exception `_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "3 7"`. While instead in a `grid` package manager invocation it's accepted. I've verified this behaviour on Python 3.7.X.

Comment: @Giova: yes, the tuple version only works for the `padx` and `pady` options of `grid` and `pack`. The `padx` and `pady` options of some widgets are different. You cannot use it for the `padx` and `pady` option of widgets. I'll try to clarify my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to specify different left and right padx for the root window in tkinter?@BryanOakley

Comment: Just a note, `padx=` and `pady=` also accepts a 2-value list, such as `padx=[10, 20]`.  Not just a 2-value tuple.  In addition, the values can be either an integer or a string, such as `padx=["10", "20"]`, and they will still work.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways of doing that you can use either `place` or `grid` or even the `pack`method.

Sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

l = Label(root, text="hello" )
l.pack(padx=6, pady=4) # where padx and pady represent the x and y axis respectively
# well you can also use side=LEFT inside the pack method of the label widget.
```

To place a widget to on basis of columns and rows , use the grid method:

```
but = Button(root, text="hello" )
but.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: The variable/constant `LEFT` is `tkinter.LEFT`, available as just `LEFT` after `from tkinter import *`

Answer (score 4):

```
-pady {10,0}
```

this way you are mentioning padding on top as 10 and below as 0.

In python code, this might look like:

```
l = Label(root, text="hello" )
l.pack(pady=(10, 0))
```

Comment: Merging this with @Anandakrishnan's answer, using eg `l.pack(pady=(0, 10))` works (not the use of a tuple).