# Remove border of Tkinter label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

The following code

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
lbl=Label(window,width='30',height='15',relief='solid')
lbl.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmG6r.jpg)

Is there any way of removing the border on one side only?

Comment: There is not but you can place your create a frame with a label inside of said frame and use it to create the border. Its a little more advanced but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Using an example on a Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613677/how-to-add-a-left-or-right-border-to-a-tkinter-label) ( I would have linked to it as a duplicate question but it needed some tweeking to compare to this OP's question. )

We can create what looks like a label with a border on 3 sides and one side without.

```
from tkinter import *

class MyLabel(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, myborderwidth=0, mybordercolor=None,
                 myborderplace='center', *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=mybordercolor)
        self.propagate(False)
        self.label = Label(self, *args, **kwargs)

        if myborderplace is 'left':
            self.label.pack(side='right')
        elif myborderplace is 'right':
            self.label.pack(side='left')
        else:
            self.label.pack()
            myborderwidth = myborderwidth * 2

        self.config(width=self.label.winfo_reqwidth() + myborderwidth)
        self.config(height=self.label.winfo_reqheight() + myborderwidth)

root=Tk()
root.geometry("50x50")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

MyLabel(root, text='Hello World', myborderwidth=2, mybordercolor='black',
        myborderplace='right').grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Would the process be any simpler using Canvas instead of Label?

Comment: @NafRose Well I am not sure. I would have to try and write up an example. You could give it a shot and see how far you get.

Answer (score 0):

If I use Canvas instead of Label, i can make a border on three sides by creating lines by the edges.
Example code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(height='250',width ='250')
canvas.create_line(251,0,251,251,width=2,fill='black')
canvas.create_line(3,3,251,3,width=2,fill='black')
canvas.create_line(3,251,252,251,width=2,fill='black')
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Which ouputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml81E.jpg)

There could be more practical ways though.