# Pad only in one direction with tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, padding

Is it possible to pad a widget only from the top and not the bottom? The pady command will always add pixels both ways... :\

Here's an example:

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

root = Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
label1 = ttk.Label(frame, text="Label 1")
label2 = ttk.Label(frame, text="Label 2")
entry = ttk.Entry(frame)

frame.grid(column=0,row=0)
label1.grid(column=0,row=0)
label2.grid(column=0,row=1,pady=15)  ## I would like to pad this only from the top
entry.grid(column=0,row=2)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `pad` using a tuple like:

```
label2.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=(15,0))
```

For more info, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178084/4203871) question and answer.