# Tkinter Inner Padding can't be on only one side

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

This might be confusing but for some odd reason using `ipadx` or `ipady` in `.pack()` with `(1,0)` or like this: `Label(root, text='Hello World').pack(ipadx=(1,0))` will always make this error: `TclError: bad ipady value "1 0": must be positive screen distance`. Trying other things like: `Label(root, text='Hello World').pack(ipadx=1)` work just fine. But [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178084/6322930) Said:

> The padding options (padx, ipadx, pady and ipady) can take a 2-tuple that represent the left/right and top/bottom padding.

So, what is happening...

And here's some complete Code that has the error too:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label(root, text='Hello World').pack(ipadx=(1, 0))

root.mainloop()
```

Update: I found that you can't do that in Tkinter, or even Tcl/Tk...

Comment: Are you by any chance using a non-English locale?

Comment: No. It was hard to explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer you linked to is wrong, and I'll update it. `ipadx` and `ipady` do not support a tuple as an argument. From the [official tcl/tk docs](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M17):

> **-ipadx** *amount*
>
> *Amount* specifies how much horizontal internal padding to leave on each side of the slave(s). *Amount* must be a valid screen distance,
>   such as 2 or .5c. It defaults to 0.
>
> **-ipady** *amount*
>
> *Amount* specifies how much vertical internal padding to leave on each side of the slave(s). *Amount* defaults to 0.
>
> **-padx** *amount*
>
> *Amount* specifies how much horizontal external padding to leave on each side of the slave(s). *Amount* may be a list of two values to
>   specify padding for left and right separately. Amount defaults to 0.
>
> **-pady** *amount*
>
> *Amount* specifies how much vertical external padding to leave on each side of the slave(s). *Amount* may be a list of two values to specify
>   padding for top and bottom separately. Amount defaults to 0.

Comment: Thank you, i ended up with a other way of sizing the widget the way i wanted.