# tkinter widget ipad(x/y) works differently than pad(x,y)

Tags: python-3.x, layout, tkinter

I am able to customize the external padding on *all four sides* of a tkinter widget using

```
widget.grid(0, 0, padx=(left_pad, right_pad), pady=(top_pad, bottom_pad))
```

However, when I replace `padx` and `pady` with `ipadx` and `ipady` respectively, I receive the error: *bad ipadx value "10 1": must be positive screen distance*

Why do they behave differently?

Comment: the ipadx and ipady are for internal padding where padx and pady are for external padding. ipadx and ipady do not support tuples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter Inner Padding can't be on only one side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196632/tkinter-inner-padding-cant-be-on-only-one-side)

Answer (score 0):

the problem Is 
 that ipadx AND ipady just need a parameter float. 
Example: ipadx=1 AND ipady=2