# I have created an Entry Widget and placed it in the grid but it doesn't show

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a front end for a customer access and on one of my pages, the entry widget that I want to place next to the label doesn't show, I don't get any errors.

I've placed it on a grid and moved it around, I have made sure nothing else is in it's part of the grid

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

newCustomerPage = Tk()
newCustomerPage.geometry('400x172') #define the size of the window
newCustomerPage.overrideredirect(True) #removes the bar at the top of the window

windowWidth = newCustomerPage.winfo_reqwidth() #Place the window in the middle of the page
windowHeight = newCustomerPage.winfo_reqheight()

positionRight = int(newCustomerPage.winfo_screenwidth()/2.3 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(newCustomerPage.winfo_screenheight()/3 - windowHeight/2)

newCustomerPage.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
print("New Customer Page set")

customerPageLabel = Label(newCustomerPage, text = "New Customer", font = ("Calibri", 25), padx = 110)#.pack(side = TOP, pady = 1)
customerPageLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
newCustNameLabel = Label(newCustomerPage, text = 'Given Name:', font = ("Calibri", 12))#.pack(side = TOP, pady = 1)
newCustNameLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
newCustNameEntry = Entry(newCustomerPage, width = 10)
newCustNameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
close = ttk.Button(newCustomerPage, text = 'Close', width = 20, command = newCustomerPage.destroy)#.pack(side = TOP, pady = 8)
close.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
```

The page opens and displays "New Customer" then directly below that in the middle of the page displays "Given Name:" then directly below that displays the "close" button which functions fine, I want the entry box to display to the right of 'newCustNameLabel' but it doesn't

Comment: You set `padx = 110` in your `customerPageLabel` which pushes everything on grid column #1 off screen. Change your geometry to `newCustomerPage.geometry('800x172')` and you will see it.

Comment: @HenryYik Thanks it worked, but it doesnt really make sense, why did it push the entry widget when it was on a different row? It didn't push the newCustNameLabel at all which was also on the same row as newCustNameEntry, isnt X the same as row? going across the screen not down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> padx: The amount specifies how much horizontal external padding to leave on each side of the slave(s), in screen units.

So by setting `padx=100` in your grid column #0, you applied padding for 100px on both sides, which pushes the `Entry` widget off screen.

Instead of using `padx`, what you should do is to set the `columnspan` of `customerPageLabel` so it can span over more than 1 column:

```
customerPageLabel = Label(newCustomerPage, text = "New Customer", font = ("Calibri", 25))
customerPageLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=2)
```

And if you want the columns to occupy all the remaining space, set a weight to the columns:

```
newCustomerPage.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
newCustomerPage.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
```

Comment: but the Entry widget was not on the same row as the top Label.

Comment: By both sides it means [padding 100][Grid column 0][padding 100][Grid column 1].

Comment: Thank you very much, does that go for every single column?

Comment: It applies for the columns you set `padx` to. So if you also set `padx` for column 1, it will be like [padding 0][Grid column 0][padding 0][padding 1][Grid column 1][padding 1]. To work around this, you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174575/adding-padding-to-a-tkinter-widget-only-on-one-side).